# How is a class diagram converted into code?

Tags: class, class-diagram

I was self-studying various UML diagrams and I understood most of them except for `Class Diagram` and `Object Diagram`.

I can not get my head around how they wil be converted into code.

The trick that I learnt is this: *all nouns become classes and verbs become methods of the classes*.

All good till there but after that, how is the diagram converted into code?
Have a look at a diagram here that I got from the internet:
[image]

So, assuming that the language is **Java**, how will you code a software based  on this?

Comment: Do you know java syntax? If yes - than what is a problem? if no - than just learn the syntax and after that go ahead.

Comment: @SergeyS What I can't get my head around is how will the GUI sit on the computer? What functions will it perform? Will the look of the GUI be different for different people, like the clerk n all? or the look of the GUI has nothing to do with class models?

Comment: A UML diagram has nothing to do with the GUI. What it represents is the structure of the internals of the software you are trying to build. Once you've got a good grasp of ObjectOriented Programming, and UML you should be able to easily convert the posted diagram to functionen code. How you want to couple that internal architecture with a GUI is a different question entirely

Comment: @RandomSort so basically, referring to the above diagram, I can provide a different GUI to different people. Like clerk n all? If you post this as an answer with a lil more detail then I will accept it :)

Comment: I have tried to elaborate in an answer, I hope you can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A UML diagram solely describes the internal architecture of a given piece of software.

The information contained in your UML diagram is therefore:

- What classes are contained
- What methods and properties do they contain
- How do they relate to each other

Each block with a header ("Train" for instance ) represents a class, listing its properties and methods.

As such the UML diagram does not state anything about a GUI or how the user interacts with the software. It is up to you or a UI/UX designer to create an interface you can implement, that uses the functionality outlined in this UML diagram.

You can think of a UML diagram as a description of the architecture of a piece of software, that is very shallow but is well suited for an overview of the project.

It is not a recipe.

I hope this was useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a class diagram, you have a representation of the classes (and its members) that you should have in code.
So, your noun/verb analysis (what you were talking about), has already been done when you have a class diagram.
A class diagram is just a visual representation of your classes, converting them to code is just easy if you know the syntax of the language that you want to use.

Comment: Ok, didn't know that there was a different UI/UX Engineer. I thought it was upto the programmer to create a UI and I could not get my head around how that could be done. Well, after reading the answers, it makes sense and I guess I can play  both the UI/UX and the coder. Thanks guys! :)